# Uncaught TypeError: 1 argument required, but only 0 present...But my function takes no arguments?

Tags: javascript, animation, onclick, arguments, typeerror

Im trying to make an empty div with a width and height and background-color move across the screen calling a function onclick. It takes no arguments. But when i click the element it says: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': 1 argument required, but only 0 present. What am i missing?

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
var containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
var box1Width = box1.clientWidth;

function animate() {
    box1.style.left = '0px';
    setTimeout(function() {
        box1.style.transition = 'left 1000ms ease';
        box1.style.left = containerWidth - box1Width + 'px';
    }, 1);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#box1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box1" onclick="animate()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error in Chrome v52

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to rename `animate` function to something else. Seems like you call not your function, but `animate` method of element `box1`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I "ticked" and voted your answer up. I can see it. But im not sure if anyone else can. It said something like..."because my reputation is less than 15, your feedback will be recorded but will not be shown live on screen". Sorry about that....

Comment: @xxkaiwaxx thats ok )

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use addEventHandler! Do not mix HTML and Javascript!

Then a handler has to be function, not the result of a function.
As in "animate" is a function, "animate()" is void.

Comment: The second is wrong. If you use attribute onclick you need to call function.